# Recursively deleting a linked list, memory was allocated using new

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void DeleteList(node** Head)
{
  if(*Head==NULL)
    return;
  node* current=*Head;
  delete[] current;
  current=NULL;
  DeleteList(&((*Head)->next));
}
```

The program crashes with a segmentation fault.

Comment: head is probably undefined and a wild pointer.

Comment: You can't use `(*Head)->next` after you `delete *Head;`.

Comment: No Head node changes(next node) with  with correct value for each call of DeleteList(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy `(*Head)->next` into another variable before you `delete[] current`. Otherwise, you're trying to access `next` in a node that has been deleted.

```
void DeleteList(node** Head)
{
  if(*Head==NULL) {
    return;
  }
  node* current=*Head;
  node* tail = current->next;
  delete current;
  DeleteList(&tail);
}
```

Also, I doubt you should be using `delete[]`. `current` is presumably just a single node, not an array of nodes. And there's no need to set `current = NULL`; this is a local variable that's just going to go away when the function ends, and you never used it afterward, so it doesn't matter what it contains.

Another solution would be to simply move `DeleteList(&((*Head)->next));` to before `delete current;`.

I'm also not sure why you call this function using a pointer to a pointer. That's usually done when you want to modify the caller's pointer. But you never do that here. But perhaps you're doing it for consistency with the rest of the linked list library, and that's OK.

Comment: `&tail` isn't what you think. :)

Comment: It's the address of a pointer to a node. That's all that's required. I know it's not the address of `current->next`, but we can't use that because we deleted `current`.

Comment: I had one doubt regarding pointer to pointer, here I want to delete a linked list which is in caller's local variable. So why don't we need to pass pointer to that. For e.g. in Push we need to pass pointer to pointer.

Comment: You only need to pass a pointer if you want to modify the caller's variable. You're not doing that. If you had `*Head = NULL;`, that would be a reason to do it.

Comment: sorry but am not getting how is delete not a modify?

Comment: When you `delete` you're just modifying what the pointer refers to, you're not modifying the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some idea what you have to do. accessing the memory after deleting is undefined behavior (*as Barmar's comments*)

```
void deleteList(list_link* item)
{
    while (item)
    {
        list_link* old = item;
        item = item->next;
        delete old;
    }
}
```